# How to raise CancelEventArgs

Tags: c#, wpf

How to raise CancelEventArgs in unit testing using C#

```
void OnCloseWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = base.DataContext as IWindowManagerService;
            if (window != null)
            {
                e.Cancel = !window.CloseWindow();
            }
        }
```

Comment: unit testing is for code files not gui's, so you should have your close event calling a method, you would then test the method

Comment: Wrong duplicate... this is about raising the event and not about testing an event that is expected to be fired from somewhere else.